# How do I specify a control as a property in my user control in WPF?

Tags: wpf-controls

#### My XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" .../>
<MyExtender TargetTextBox=? .../>
```

#### My C#:

```
MyExtender : UserControl
{
    public TargetTextBox { get; set; }
}
```

How do I set the TargetTextBox property in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
<TextBox Name="tb">Something</TextBox>
<my:MyExtender TargetTextBox="{Binding ElementName=tb}" />
```

but this requires TargetTextBox to be a DependencyProperty. Change MyExtender.xaml.cs to:

```
 public partial class MyExtender : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
{
    public MyExtender()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetTextBoxPropery = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("TargetTextBox", typeof(TextBox), typeof(MyExtender));

    public TextBox TargetTextBox
    {
        get { return (TextBox)GetValue(TargetTextBoxPropery); }
        set { SetValue(TargetTextBoxPropery, value); }
    }

}
```

And you should be set.